# failed to resolve :com.android:android 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

app build.gradel

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    // classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
}
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     mavenLocal()
     jcenter()
     maven {
          url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
     }
     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
     defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.packagename"
          minSdkVersion 14
          targetSdkVersion 26
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
api 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
//){
//        exclude group:'com.android.support' , module: 'support-annotations' version '26.1.0'
//        exclude group:'com.android.support' , module: 'support-v4' version '26.1.0'
//        exclude group:'com.android.support' , module: 'multidex' version '1.0.1'
//        exclude group:'com.android.support' , module: 'cardview-v7' version '26.1.0'
//
//    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
//    implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.7@aar') {
//        transitive = true
//    }
//    implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.7@aar') {
//        transitive = true
//    }
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0'
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.5.0'
//api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.daprlabs.aaron:cardstack:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1062'
implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.6.3'
implementation 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'
// implementation 'com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-core:0.2.7-20161111.083903-7'
//  implementation 'com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-theme-material:0.2.7-20161110.030043-6'
implementation 'com.eowise:recyclerview-stickyheaders:0.5.2@aar'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.2@aar'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.3.41.1@aar'
}
```

Root build.gradel

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {    
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
  //  classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
} 
allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    /* 3) Add the Creative SDK Maven repo URL */
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
 }
 }
task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradelwapper.property

```
#Mon Nov 13 11:59:09 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

When its run perfectly in 2.3.3 but when i upgrade on 3.0 it gives error 
so i create new blank projct in 3.0 and move all java and resource file 
also incluede all lib but it show this error 
**merging code from android studio 2.3.3 to 3.0 canary** 
Thanks in advance

Comment: change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Comment: Why are you using a Canary version of Android Studio 3.0 when it has been officially released? So first upgrade to it and and change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`

Comment: i was already try with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9' and 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0' both

Answer (score 0):

So first update to [Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Then in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

change `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip`

to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

And in your **build.gradle** try this (you'll have to change the `applicationId`):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
    }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
//    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.custom.test"
        minSdkVersion  14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '26.1.0'
    AAVersion = '3.3.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"

    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0' // Avoid that. Import only what is needed
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.5.0'

    implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1062'
    implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.6.3'

    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.3.41.1@aar'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.daprlabs.aaron:cardstack:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.eowise:recyclerview-stickyheaders:0.5.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    implementation 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
}
```

Comment: You need to clean your imports. For example, you import `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` when you don't seem to use it. And as far as I know, Glide is very similar to Picasso, so use one or the other but not them both. It'll add consistency and reduce you app final size and build time.

Comment: same  issue dear

Comment: Did you clear the cache of both Android Studio and project?